# What is the difference between a multiplication (eg. tf.math.multiply()) and a multiplication layer (eg. tf.keras.layers.multiply())?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, tensor

I thought that `tf.keras.layers.multiply()` was a wrapper for element-wise multiplication to use in a model. But it seems to behave different to a normal multiplication like `tf.math.multiply()`.
The normal multiplication works as expected for large data shapes whereas the layer leads to an out of memory error. The multiply layer tries to allocate a tensor of shape[input_shape, input_shape]. This leads to the out of memory error.

Why does it do this when a element-wise multiplication using the other function works without allocating that much memory? What is the difference between the function and the layer version of the function?

EDIT:
code example for `tf.math.multiply()`

```
random1 = np.random.random((960000,))
random2 = np.random.random((960000,))
multiplied = tf.math.multiply(random1, random2)
```

this runs as expected.

code example for `tf.keras.multiply()`

```
random1 = np.random.random((960000,))
random2 = np.random.random((960000,))
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(960000,))
out = tf.keras.layers.multiply((inputs, random2))

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
test = model(random1)
```

this leads to `ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[960000,960000]...`

Answer (score 1):

I finally found and solved the problem.
Somehow `inputs` was of shape (,960000) in the model part even though it was of shape (960000,) originally.
A forced reshape in the layer like `out = tf.keras.layers.multiply((tf.reshape(inputs, shape=(960000,)), random2))` did the trick.

Edit:
To be on the safe side both inputs to the multiply layer should be force reshaped, in my original code I had to reshape the `random2` equivalent.

Editedit:
The reason seems to be that a model expects a batch dimension and reshapes inputs accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your model definition is wrong. Here is the working code (w/o OOM).

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

# with np
random1 = np.random.random((960000,))
random2 = np.random.random((960000,))
print(tf.math.multiply(random1, random2)[:20])

# within keras layer 
print(tf.keras.layers.multiply((random1, random2))[:20])

# within keras model 
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(960000,))
out = tf.keras.layers.multiply((inputs, inputs))
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
print(model(random1)[:20])
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[0.21294616 0.06710127 0.17013486 0.10901891 0.29350176 0.02249815
 0.35850803 0.28249435 0.74084921 0.08892484 0.06768416 0.096876
 0.53759075 0.72584273 0.05068911 0.7966705  0.57350002 0.23978052
 0.1561444  0.10930546], shape=(20,), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(
[0.21294616 0.06710126 0.17013486 0.10901891 0.29350176 0.02249815
 0.35850805 0.28249437 0.7408492  0.08892484 0.06768416 0.096876
 0.53759074 0.7258427  0.05068911 0.79667044 0.5735     0.23978053
 0.15614441 0.10930545], shape=(20,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[0.16445962 0.50742036 0.0419461  0.02044158 0.24636301 0.00493375
 0.21818672 0.12314986 0.82684237 0.25927284 0.9177247  0.84513015
 0.37434673 0.79354537 0.22670402 0.7000397  0.45317554 0.313896
 0.44795534 0.1293014 ], shape=(20,), dtype=float32)
```